# Delete from Core Data

Tags: ios, database, swift, core-data

I work on an iOS App application that stores some data in Core Data. I found a problem when I had to delete specific data from Core Data.

Although it says that the delete was successfull, the number of elements stored are the same.

Can you take a look ?

Here's the code :

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Session")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do
    {
        var session = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Session]

            managedContext.deleteObject(session.first!)
        if session.first!.deleted {
            print("Succesfully deleted")
            print(session.count)
        }
        else {
            print("Unsuccesfull")
        }


    } catch  {
            print("Detele error : \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: You need to save the context – and your code will reliably crash if the fetched array is empty (the `do - catch` expression doesn't catch that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Vadian said, you forgot to save the context.

So let implement it:

```
do {
   try managedContext.save()  
} catch let error as NSError {
   print(error)
}
```

Comment: Actually the `save` line can also be put in the existing `do`  block.

Comment: Ahh , i forgot about saving, now it works .. thank you !

Comment: the thanksgiving is much more pleasure when you upvote or/and mark the answer as correct ;)